# Traducción de nombres propios

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

Cuando era niño me parecía muy divertido leer material escrito en España sobre personajes famosos (históricos o de ficción). Así, `George Washington` y `Luke Skywalker` se convertían en `Jorge Washington` y `Lucas Trotacielos`. Esto no ocurría tan a menudo con material escrito en México (excepto en algunos materiales escolares). Ahora, años más tarde, me parece una costumbre pretenciosa y un poco ridícula. Es como escribir en inglés sobre los famosos artistas `Savior Dali` y `Paul Picasso`. Así pues,

- ¿Es realmente aceptable esta costumbre?
- ¿Es común actualmente? ¿Dónde?

Comment: ¿Lucas Trotacielos? Nunca lo había oído. Bueno, lo de "españolizar" los nombres era algo que se hacía antes. Ya no se hace, con la excepción de los miembros de casas reales y similares. Así, la Reina de Inglaterra es Isabel, su hijo es Carlos...

Comment: También se hace en inglés, como con Joseph Stalin.

Comment: Yo distinguiría entre los casos en que la grafía es la misma y en los que no. En los primeros solamente se traducen los nombres reales, como @MikMik comenta. En los segundos, se adopta una grafía latina del cirílico Ио́сиф, lo que da lugar a traducciones más cercanas y leíbles.

Comment: Podrías poner una referencia a ese material? de que año estamos hablando? Soy español y no he oido en mi vida (y fui al estreno de "La guerra de las galaxias") ni Jorge Washington (que según lo que comentas debería ser Güasinton) ni de Lucas Trotacielos, a no ser que estes hablando de bromas como "from lost to the river".

Comment: Eso sí, somos tan ridículos que decismos "Nueva York" y en cambio hablamos de "Terrasa" ahí si que te doy la razón :-)

Comment: ¿Lucas Trotacielos? Soy español y nunca he leído ni oido nada así...

Comment: [Una pregunta relacionada](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1435) sobre este tema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El nombre con el que designamos las cosas es parte del lenguaje y en las épocas anteriores a la globalización de los medios cada población se ponía de acuerdo en cómo nombrar territorios, países, eventos y personas foráneas que fueren de su interés.  Así es como funcionan los lenguajes y de ahí que reyes, embajadores y pensadores, santos y otros personajes históricos tuvieren distintos nombres en distintos idiomas.  La ortografía y la pronunciación también cambia dentro de un idioma y eso afecta también a los nombres propios.

Es así como *Πλάτων (Plátōn)* es hoy conocido en español como **Platón** y en inglés como **Plato** (pronunciado */pleitou/*).  En los idiomas en los que los nombres propios declinan por caso (como el latín), los nombres extranjeros declinan también: (*Σωκράτης* [Sócrates]: *Socrates*, *Socratem*, *Socratis*).

La moda de darle más relevancia al nombre en la lengua original es un producto de las comunicaciones modernas y la importancia dada a la identidad propia en un mundo globalizado.  Desde luego, somos parte de ese mundo globalizado y por ello nos suena absurdo hablar de Jorge Washington.  Hoy en día la traducción de nombres para personajes contemporáneos parece exclusiva para la realeza europea.

Entonces la regla de oro: se traducen los nombres de la realeza europea (*Isabel de Inglaterra*, *Catalina de Cambridge*, *Felipe de Bélgica*) [nótese que Felipe es *Philippe* en francés y *Filip* en flamenco], los personajes históricos que han tenido relevancia en el mundo hispano (*Tomás Moro*, *Héctor*, *Jesús*, *Confucio*, *Vladimir Lenin*), los países (*Costa de Marfil*, *Timor Oriental*, *Sudán del Sur*), ciudades y otros topónimos con nombres establecidos en la literatura hispana (*Ciudad del Cabo*, *Aquisgrán*, *Jerusalén*, *Londres*), mientras que la gran mayoría de términos contemporáneos usan la ortografía original o una romanización más o menos aceptada.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta.  Antes era normal, ahora es menos común pero depende de la situación.  También hay que tener en cuenta el intento del autor original (por eso, tradúcense los nombres en _El señor de los anillos_) y el tema y la audiencia esperada.  Así que en libros de historia no sería recomendable traducirlos, pero en los narrativos, no habría problema especialmente cuando los nombres originales son fácilmente descompuestos en elementos léxicos y corresponden a su carácter (por eso, Winterhaven de _Juego de tronos_ es Invernalia, bien traducido en mi opinión)

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, es común en ciertas situaciones y para el nombre de ciertas personas.

Es muy normal, por ejemplo, para miembros de la realeza de los distintos países europeos con nombre cristiano. Así, hablamos de la reina Isabel de Inglaterra, o [Carolina de Mónaco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxIQk1TpR2I) (disculpas por el enlace gamberro). He visto alguna revista del corazón referirse a Kate Middleton por su nombre antes de casada, y ahora como Catalina de Cambridge.

Es cierto que antiguamente era más habitual. Algunos nombres como Jorge Washington han quedado obsoletos, pero otros de figuras históricas como Tomás Moro o Erasmo de Rotterdam prevalecen hasta hoy.

Como alguien comenta, esto es habitual en otros idiomas también. Por ejemplo, salvo quizás en Italia, nadie conoce a Cristóbal Colón como Cristoforo Colombo.

Answer (score 3):

- *¿Es realmente aceptable esta costumbre?*

En el pasado era más aceptable traducir los nombres de pila, ya que existía la idea de que no se trataba de nombres distintos sino de variantes del mismo nombre. Es lo más natural que a un Martín que recorra Europa, en Alemania lo llamen *Martin* y en Italia *Martino*. De la misma manera, se consideraba normal, cuando se escribía en castellano, llamar Tomás Edison a *Thomas Edison*.

Ahora que la globalización nos acostumbró a los nombres de pila extranjeros, ya no se considera que Martín y *Martin*, o Tomás y *Thomas* sean el mismo nombre. Sin embargo, los asentados quedan traducidos: León Tolstoy, Nicolás Maquiavelo, etc.

- *¿Es común actualmente? ¿Dónde?*

Iba a decir que es común en la ficción, especialmente en los doblajes mexicanos (aunque mucho más en el pasado), y más especialmente en las obras para niños. Sin embargo, en mi opinión, ahí no se trata de traducir los nombres sino de traducir o adaptar las ideas o imágenes que conllevan. No es “TitoEsponja PantalonesCuadrados” sino “Bob Esponja”, no es “Lucas Caminacielo” sino “Trotacielos” (creo que tuve el mismo libro ilustrado ;) ), etc. Ese tipo de “traducción” me parece perfectamente aceptable. De otra manera, “Skywalker” o “Squarepants” se pierden; da lo mismo que se llamen Pérez.

Comment: Mal ejemplo. No da lo mismo si se llaman Pérez :)

Comment: Pero si aprecio la idea de traducciones no literales que preservan el significado del original. El problema es que el original muchas veces se elige tanto por la connotación, como por la música de sus silabas, y esa se pierde.

Comment: Cuando era niño en cómics y televisión, la identidad secreta de Batman era Bruno Díaz.  Hoy es Bruce Waine.  Campanita acompañaba a Peter Pan en sus aventuras, hoy Tinckerbell tiene su propia serie.  Tribilín era el mejor amigo del ratón Mickey, hoy es Goofie.  Por otro lado carezco de referentes para entender porque los Sidekick de Krusty en Los Simpson (diré los Simpson, no los Simpsons), se apellidan Patiño en la versión latinoamericana doblada en México.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Es un mexicanismo. Mirá [acá](http://www.academia.org.mx/diccionarios/DICAZ/p.htm): **patiño.** m. Ayudante de payaso.

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez Se ve que me quedó tu apellido en el subconsciente mientras escribía la respuesta :)

Answer (score 2):

Hoy mismo ha aparecido en la página de la Fundéu un [artículo](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/jorge-alejandro-luis-nombre-del-principe-de-cambridge/) al respecto. Además de los miembros de casas reales, se hispanizan los nombres de los papas, aunque esto último es habitual en casi todos los idiomas del mundo.

Comment: Pero no lo hacen cuando el papa se llama Benito.

Comment: @vorbote Benedicto y Benito son variantes del mismo nombre. Tradicionalmente, en el caso de los papas, se ha utilizado la variante Benedicto. Es similar a lo que ocurre tradicionalmente con los nombres de los monarcas llamados James en el Reino Unido, cuyo nombre se ha venido traduciendo como Jacobo en lugar del más habitual Jaime o Santiago, también variantes del mismo nombre.

Answer (score -1):

No hay ninguna regla oficial que dictamine si es 'aceptable' la 'costumbre' o no.
Es común, sí, particularmente en países dónde el esfuerzo por aprender inglés (o cualquier otro idioma en general) es pobre o inexistente.

Intentar traducir nombres es una tarea futil y sumamente ilógica dado que:

- La mayoría de los nombres, a nivel mundial, carecen de equivalentes en otros idiomas
- Los únicos equivalentes pertenecen/existen, en su mayoría, entre paises que comparten una religión, e inclusive entonces, suelen estar limitados a nombres que aparecen en textos religiosos.
- Propicia la actitud 'anti-subtítulos' o 'anti aprendizaje de lenguajes foráneos' y con ello, hace que las películas dobladas proliferen.

Saliendo de lo neutral, en lo personal me parece una costumbre pésima. No se logra gana, no se gana nada, la gran mayoría de las veces no se puede, es un síntoma de un mal mayor: la renuencia a aprender otros idiomas y no sorpresivamente, lo podemos ver todo el tiempo en las pésimas películas dobladas que plagan a latino-américa.

De la misma forma que una película doblada es una absoluta basura porque destruye todo el trabajo de un actor, traducir nombres le quita el 'sabor' o 'magia' particular al nombre y al personaje =/

Comment: Aunque coincido a grandes rasgos en tu preferencia por no traducir los nombres, lo de que propicie una actitud hostil hacia el aprendizaje de otros idiomas o hacia las películas con subtítulos no lo veo poe ningún lado y me parece un _non sequitur_. Llevas tu prejuicio demasiado lejos. La traducción española de las novelas de "El Señor de los anillos" es notable porque traduce los nombres propios (p.ej. _Bolsón_ por Baggins, _Sotomonte_ por Underhill, o _Trancos_ por Strider) y no sólo no me pareció ridículo en absoluto cuando lo leí a los 14 años, sino muy natural.

Comment: Hay muchísimas novelas en los que el nombre del personaje es muy relevante puesto que significa algo en el original y que si no se traducen pierde bastante.

Comment: deStrangis: has leído el señor de los anillos en su idioma original y comparado dicha versión con la traducción española? Aunque sí, debo admitir que hay raras excepciones dónde la calidad de la traducción es muy buena como en el señor de los anillos, pero inclusive así es decir que te pareció natural es porque era la primera vez que lo leíste. Si hubieras escuchado cualquier detalle sobre la novela con sus nombres originales, y luego la hubieras leido en español... te parecería igual de raro que 'alberto einstein'.

Comment: Por último pero no menos importante, como dije, el 99% de los nombres no se traduce, lo cual puedes ver en justamente, el señor de los anillos. Bilbo, Sauron, etc. - obviamente no hay traducciones para esos nombres, entonces para que traducir algunos apellidos y apodos como Baggins y Strider si todo lo demás se va a quedar igual, que se logró con ello?

De cualquier modo, el problema de la actitud anti-aprendizaje tiene lugar principalmente en la televisión, no en los libros (dado que casi nadie lee aquí en México). Pero bueno, explicar eso no es posible en este bloque de comentarios.

Comment: Creo que es erróneo pensar que es una actitud de “no querer aprender otra lengua.” - En una película el doblaje tiene sentido cuando es más importante contar la historia que destacar la interpretación actoral.  Un apodo significa algo (caso _Strider_ v/s _Trancos_), cuando es así una palabra extranjera en la historia no aporta.  ¿Qué significa _Sauron_ en inglés? - traducir es contar la historia en otro idioma y aunque siempre hay fallas son decisiones que toma el traductor.

Comment: Hay otras traducciones que para mí carecen de sentido: ¿Cuál es la razón para traducir _Bruce Waine_ como _Bruno Díaz_, cuando no se hizo lo propio con _Clark Kent_?  Es probable que el traductor original no estuviera pensando sólo en contar la historia sino en lograr algún tipo de familiaridad con el lector y si eso se logra.  Pero creo que la decisión no es motivada por “cuidado aprenden inglés.”

Comment: Cómo puede ser más importante 'contar la historia' que la interpretación actoral en una película cuando es precisamente esta la que hace que la historia cobre vida? Las buenas actuaciones rescatan malos diálogos y películas, no al revés. La interpretación actoral es la característica principal que distingue al cine de otros modos o medios de contar historias.

Comment: Respecto a los nombres, aún cuando traduces Trancos por Strider, todo el desarrollo del personaje es completamente ajeno al hecho de que camina con grandes zancadas o pasos largos. El 99.999% de las descripciones que le dan vida al personaje de Aragorn no dependen del pequeño dato sobre su forma de dar los pasos. Solamente si esta fuese central al desarrollo del personaje sería entonces indiscutible la necesidad de traducirlo.

Comment: Por último pero no menos importante, respecto a por qué este tipo de detalles, a mi parecer, no fomentan el aprendizaje de otras lenguas: Si no te ves expuesto a nombres, palabras y conceptos foráneos que no entiendes, la necesidad, deseo o impulso de ir y descubrirlos es por ende menor. Y el problema es que, por más que se esfuerzen los traductores en traducir, hay conceptos, sutilezas y demás detalles que no tienen equivalentes en otros idiomas y que para ser aprovechados al máximo, requieren que ahondemos en los idiomas originales. Esto supone, claro, un interés genuino por parte del lector

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que, en general, traducir los nombres no es buena idea. Pero *El Señor de los Anillos* no es un buen ejemplo para oponerse a estas traducciones. Tolkien escribió que había traducido o adaptado los nombres del oestrón al inglés. Uno de los apéndices del libro explica por qué y también cuáles eran los nombres originales de los personajes y lugares. Por tanto, mantener los nombres ingleses en la versión española es contrario al espíritu del libro.

Comment: @deStrangis: Tolkien en persona escribió la [Guia de nombres del Señor de los Anillos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translations_of_The_Lord_of_the_Rings#Tolkien.27s_.22Guide_to_the_Names_in_The_Lord_of_the_Rings.22) para que las traducciones fueran consistentes entre sí y con el significado y tono originales. Desafortunadamente, en esto Tolkien es la excepción, no la norma.