# Are names of international figures still translated routinely in Mexican universities?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, méxico, nombres-propios, lenguaje-académico

In the 1970's in Mexican universities (at least the provincial ones), names of historical figures were routinely translated, e.g.

> Adam Smith --> Adán Smith
>
> Albert Einstein --> Alberto Einstein
>
> Karl Marx --> Carlos Marx

Is this still the case currently?

Comment: Very related: [Traducción de nombres propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4175/1674)

Comment: Would be interesting if you went through the proposed duplicate. It solves quite a lot of the question, at least regarding the rule. Regarding the usage in Mexico, [angus's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4185/1674) says _Iba a decir que es común en la ficción, especialmente en los doblajes mexicanos (aunque mucho más en el pasado), y más especialmente en las obras para niños_.

Comment: @fedorqui - I read it.  It was interesting.  My specific focus here is higher education.  I hope that clarification helps.

Comment: If the focus is "higher education" or "Mexican culture" then it is off-topic because it is not about Spanish language. Am I wrong @aparente001?

Comment: @DGaleano - I'm not the greatest at writing questions -- on any SE site, frankly.  Still, I hope I can successfully clarify this question so as to get an answer, because I am interested to know about this. // It's true that there's some intersection here of language and culture.  But I don't see this as a purely culture question.

Comment: That's why I did not flagged it but only asked you.  :-)

Comment: I have narrowed the focus.

Comment: @DGaleano - Higher education is the setting.  Different words are used in different settings.  When you see the doctor about a urinary tract infection, you probably don't use the word "pipí," which you'd commonly use at home with your family.  This is definitely a language question.  But culture and regionalisms have some overlap -- that is unavoidable.

Comment: Oops that was a long while ago. I understand your point and again as I said before that is why i did not flagged it as off-topic. It was marked as duplicated that is a different matter. Sorry.